# Could someone explain me purpose of aj5 and aj scripts in the bin directory of installed AspectJ framework

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Here the screenshot of containing the bin folder in AspectJ framework.

[image]

Comment: Please post text, not images, although I'm not sure either are necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are for [Load Time Weaving](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#enabling-load-time-weaving). `aj5` is for java 5, `aj` is for java 1.4.

Here is types of weaving supported by AspectJ:

1. Compile-time weaving is the simplest approach. When you have the source code for an application, ajc will compile from source and produce woven class files as output. The invocation of the weaver is integral to the ajc compilation process. The aspects themselves may be in source or binary form. If the aspects are required for the affected classes to compile, then you must weave at compile-time. Aspects are required, e.g., when they add members to a class and other classes being compiled reference the added members.
2. Post-compile weaving (also sometimes called binary weaving) is used to weave existing class files and JAR files. As with compile-time weaving, the aspects used for weaving may be in source or binary form, and may themselves be woven by aspects.
3. [Load-time weaving (LTW)](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw.html) is simply binary weaving defered until the point that a class loader loads a class file and defines the class to the JVM. To support this, one or more "weaving class loaders", either provided explicitly by the run-time environment or enabled through a "weaving agent" are required.